# Generating a random array of objects (randomic profile persons)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math, javascript-objects

Generate an array with 10 objects of this type: {
name: "Person X",
(where instead of X you will put a progressive number)
sex: < "M"
or "F" > ,
(should be random)
age: < number between 18 and 100)
}

The result should be something like this:

```
[{
        "Name": "Person 1",
        "sex": "F",
        "eta": 22
    },
    {
        "Name": "Person 2",
        "sex": "F",
        "eta": 56
    },
    {
        "Name": "Person 3",
        "sex": "M",
        "eta": 33
    },
    ...
]
```

need to use "for"loop and Math.random to generate randomers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution.
The following code generates 10 people with a name, sex, and eta and appends it to the people array using a for loop and Math.random.

```js
let people = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    people.push(person = {
        Name: "Person " + (i+1),
        sex: Math.round(Math.random()) ? "M" : "F",
        eta: Math.floor((Math.random() * (100 - 18) + 18))
    });
}
```